# Call SOAP webservice(Made in .NET) through Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, soap

I am developing one mobile web application.

In this, i want to call a Web Service and fetch data from their using Java Script only.

I searched a lot and try to implement some code also but it didn't help me out.

One thing is that the Web Service was made in **.NET** using SOAP.

So, please help me to solve it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

One easy would be to create an ASP.NET Web API Http service wrapper around your current webservice and use jQuery to access it. This will be much simpler than using JS to access a SOAP service.

More on ASP.NET Web API: http://www.asp.net/web-api

Comment: Thanks for reply. I want to call this .NET SOAP Web Service using JavaScript, JQuery or ajax. So, help me out to do that.